# What is the purpose of .dfm files in C++

Tags: c++builder

I have used C++ in Unix and I am aware of .h and .cpp files, but I have never worked on C++ builder and now I have got a project that contains .cpp, .h and .dfm files. So what is the the purpose of .dfm files and how do we use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dfm files describe a form, and typically have an associated cpp file and h file for other aspects of the form's class. They are typically edited using the IDE in C++ Builder.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply 
can you tell me regarding 

Identifier 
PropertyType
ValuesEx

Comment: Can you help me with any example. it would be very kind of you

Comment: I have to add one field to a form so do i need to change in .dfm form also

Comment: You do not edit a .dfm file directly.  When you open the associated .cpp file in the IDE, a visual Form Designer is available to edit the Form contents visually.  Design-time controls and property values are then saved in the .dfm file and are loaded into the Form object at run-time.

Comment: In later versions of C++Builder, the dfm is a text file, so you can actually edit it (if you know what you're doing), and it can participate in source control.